# Проблема с вычислением значений арифметических выражений

Tags: c++

Задача такая: написать программу, которая запрашивает четыре целых числа a, b, c и d. Программа должна вывести в первой строке через пробел два значения арифметических выражений:

1. (a + b)<sup>3</sup>
2. (c − d)<sup>4</sup>

Во второй строке программа должна вывести через пробел три значения арифметических выражений:

1. (a + 2ab + b)<sup>2</sup>
2. (c − (3cd)<sup>2</sup> + 5)<sup>2</sup>
3. 6(b<sup>2</sup> − 4ac)<sup>2</sup>

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int a, b, c, d; 

    cout << (a+b) * (a+b) * (a+b) * (a+b) << " "
         << (c-b) * (c-b) * (c-b) * (c-b)
         << endl;

    cout << ((a + (2*a*b) + b) * (a + (2*a*b) + b)) << " "
         << (c - ((3*c*d) * (3*c*d)) + 5) * (c - ((3*c*d) * (3*c*d)) + 5) << " "
         << 6 * (((b*b) - 4*a*b)) * ((b*b) - 4*a*b)
         << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Этот код должен выводить:

```
27 1
49 18496 384
```

А выводит:

```
0 0
0 25 0
```

Помогите разобраться: что не так?

Comment: вы переменные даже не инициализировали!

Comment: Программа должна запрашивать четыре числа. Где она это делает?

Comment: Мда, люди видимо даже не пытаются найти решение перед тем как идти на форум. И ведь в теории к вопросу не придерешься, код ведь есть.

Comment: Этот пример наглядно показывает, что в локальной области  всегда лучше инициализировать обьявленные   обьекты встроенных типов.  В обратном случаи  они могут иметь значение по умолчанию, а могут и содержать мусор

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Инициализировать - это очень хорошо и правильно, если у вас есть осмысленный и содержательный инициализатор.  Если же инициализатор пока не готов, то инициализиация "чем попало" приведет лишь к заметанию ошибок под ковер.

Comment: @AnT,  постарайтесь понять суть, а не цепляться к словам, чтобы критиковать. Речь не шла о решении задачи, и это комментарий, а не ответ, а в комментарии я могу пропустить  слово "междупрочем". Если вы хотите показать, что вы тут самый умный, то извените, но получаете обратный эффект

Comment: @AnT, а мне кажется, AnT как раз таки понял суть вашего комментария.

Answer (score 2):

Откуда программа эти значения по вашему брать должна? Если с консоли, то выглядеть это должно так:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int a,b,c,d; 
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    cout << pow(a+b, 3) <<" " << pow(c-b, 4)<<endl;
    //аналогично второе выражение
    return 0; 
}
```

Чтобы код не был таким громоздким используйте [`pow()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) из `cmath`

Comment: За использование `pow` для вычисления степеней целых чисел надо наказывать жестоко! Вот что автор вопроса сделал исключительно правильно - так это то, что он обошелся без `pow`. Написать надо было менее громоздко, разумеется - не повторяя одну и ту же разность. Но без `pow` в любом случае.

Comment: `pow(a, b)` из `cmath` - это фактически `exp(a * log(b))`. Для целочисленных вычислений не пригоден.